# Peut-on traduire « constraint » par « contrainte » en mathématiques ?

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie, mathématiques

J’ai vu qu’en anglais « contrainte » se dit « constraint ».  Je sais que ce mot s’emploie aussi en mathématiques, pour dire « condition », et je veux savoir si on peut également le traduire par « contrainte » dans ce cadre. J’aimerais aussi savoir si on peut « contraindre » quelque chose, autrement dit qu’on « prescrit une exigence ».  Dernièrement, je veux savoir si « assujetti à » est une bonne traduction de « subject to » pourvu que la terminaison de « assujetti » convienne au genre et au nombre du nom qui suit.

J’ai tenté de traduire ce mot et les tournures qui le contiennent en changeant de langue sur Wikipédia, mais ce site ne fournit qu’une page sur ce sujet. Voici le lien :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dans le cas de l'optimisation, l'expression est transparente et on parle *d'optimisation sous contrainte*, de *maximum sous contrainte*…

Plus généralement je dirais plutôt que quelque chose est *soumis* à des contraintes ou qu'il *répond* à des contraintes plutôt que *assujeti*, mais ta version reste compréhensible.